# INSERT IGNORE Fails with auto_increment

Tags: php, sql, insert, auto-increment, insert-into

My goal is to only execute a SQL Insert if the same value not exists.

this is my table1:

```
id(auto_increment)
version(string)
```

My Query looks like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (version) VALUES ('12345');
```

The problem is that the ignore statement not work because every row is different because of the id column (auto_increment).

Anybody here have a Solution to avoid double saving the same values?

Solution:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (version)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '12345') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT version FROM table1 WHERE version = '12345'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has nothing to do with the auto-incremented column.

You need a unique constraint/index on `version`:

```
alter table table1 constraint unq_table1_version unique (version);
```

I also don't recommend `insert ignore` for this purpose.  It might ignore other errors.  Instead, use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table1 (version) 
    values ('12345')
    on duplicate key update version = values(version);  -- this is a no-op
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i already found another way to solve the problem! i added the solution:)

Comment: @letsTry420 . . . Your solution is not multi-thread safe.  That is, duplicates can still appear in the table when they are inserted at approximately the same time.  It is much, much better to have the database ensure data integrity.